# Event toaster for visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

I often use visual studio 2005 side-by-side with visual studio 2008. Do you remember the visual studio 2005 power-toy event toaster? You could configure it to pop a balloon in the system tray when a build was complete.

Is there a FREE plug-in for visual studio 2008 that does the same thing ? I really miss the event toaster. I used to zone out during long builds and the friendly POP sound it made when the build was complete would wake me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com) can show popups when builds are complete.

You'll  if you add the [visual studio plugin](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/plugins/visualstudio) for it.

Works with vs05 and vs08.

Comment: Perfect !! . works great. I just have to remember to start growl before starting visual studio and it works !