# VS 2015 not beeping batch file or build success

Tags: c#, build, beep

I want to make VS2015 beep on build success but want to be able to decide on what solutions to do that.
I have seen that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629125/how-can-i-get-visual-studio-to-beep-at-me-if-a-build-succeeds) but would like to make it simpler.

So I have followed [that](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt) and make a batch file that beeps when launched.

In short when I launch it, it writes BEEP and beeps.

But when I put in post build event the line C:\Development\beep.bat it doesn't beep but writes the BEEP label but doesn't make a sound.
What's wrong in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your batch file is echoing Ctrl-G to the standard output stream. The stdout is captured by Visual Studio for post build events, so you get the Ctrl-G sent to the build log, not to the OS.

Comment: No. You would have to write a small command shell application that addressed the speaker directly.